# WordPress qtranslate, show post in one language

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

When I add text to post in en, in spain language I get also english posts. Maybe are some settings that if I add text only to english in spain will display nothing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto Settings -> Languages and check *"Hide Untranslated Content"*